# PSPICE non sinking voltage source

Tags: operational-amplifier, protection, pspice, current-sink

In an ideal world, most power supplies have a current sourcing feature but not a sinking feature. In this circuit, you can see that the 15V supply is sinking current. How can I prevent this in Pspice?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software. How do you know the current direction? You haven't posted enough of the circuit for us to add up all the currents. Can you fix?

Comment: Cheat with a diode in series?

Comment: @Transistor In pspice, if the current is +, it means that it enters from that pin.
If the current is -, it means it comes out of that pin

Comment: You've something weird going on then. Where is the 4.3 mA through U3 (Zener diode) coming from? Start adding voltage measurement points and check that your + and - 15 V are what you think they are. Are the op-amp V+ and V- correct? (Normally we'd have V+ on top.)

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/op-amp-input-overvoltage-protection.html check out this.  its the normal ,we are calling opamp input protection clamp.when input takes 24V .We direct the current to the power supply to protect the inputs.

Comment: @Electronx in that case, you can't prevent V31 from sinking current without compromising input protection. If it stops sinking current, it stops being a 15V source, and the clamp doesn't clamp any more.

Comment: Also, being a high pass filter, with the input AC coupled via C7 (and C8)  this current cannot be coming from input source V30, unless for some reason these readings are not the DC operating point; perhaps instantaneous values immediately after power on, when C7 and C8 are initially discharged? After everything's settled, there should be no difference in potential between the inverting and non-inverting inputs, and the clamps should not be clamping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a clue in the 72.73 μA flowing into R2 (330 kΩ): -

[image]

That current and that resistance implies a voltage source of 24 volts somewhere in your circuit and, hey-presto, there it is on the 2nd and 3rd diagram: -

[image]

So, it seems to me that the current you see running into your supply is negative and this should be no surprise given the 24 volts at the input. It's likely that PSPICE calculates the currents at the initial point (rather than waiting for everything to settle down.

> *How can I prevent this in Pspice?*

If it's a problem then you have to redesign your circuit. It isn't a PSpice problem that requires some kind of PSpice fix.

Comment: Yes, this is related to the fact that the input is 24V when the load is removed from a circuit. In this case, the maximum value of the Vinput input can be 15.5V, otherwise the opamp will burn out. That's why I need to direct the currents to another point, which is the +15power supply.

Comment: Then, I want to transfer it to GND through a TVS resistor because if the power source sinking current cannot be made, the voltage increase will occur here or the power supply may be damaged.

Comment: If a voltage increase occurs, we will see the voltage drop on the 15+(voltage increase)+Shotckey diode on the input pin of the opamp, and this result will damage the non-inverting pin.

Comment: The 24 volt will be a short surge so, using a regular zener diode or TVS could work if you are trying to avoid too much current back-feeding your 15 volt supply. Clearly C7 and C8 prevent this from having anything other than a short term effect.

Comment: The OPAx192 is good for 36 volts so, why do you think there'll be a problem if you did nothing? @Electronx

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/NW6I3YP.png
It may be 0.5V higher than the supply voltage. I am supplying it with 15Volt. In this case, wouldn't there be maximum ratings for 15.5Vinput? or 20.5Volt?
As far as I understand, we assume the voltage we are feeding at that moment is 15V,so our max input voltage can be15.5V. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, if you have chosen incorrect protection diodes then yes, it may rise more than 0.5 volt above the supply rail. That's the whole point of diodes U2 and U3 <-- they have to have a forward volt-drop less than 0.5 volts when a surge current passes through the 2 kohm resistor (R3). That surge will be 3.315 mA so, check the data sheets for those diodes and see if they are OK.

Comment: If you also read the data sheet for the op-amp you'll see that the maximum input pin current is +/- 10 mA so, given that with 24 volts at the input you can't generate more than 3.315 mA I would say you are OK.

Comment: In this case, where will I send the 3.15mA current? What if I use a 15V zener diode so that it flows over the zener? When I use a TVS diode with a standoff voltage of 15 and a breakdown voltage of 15.3, the Vin pin reaches a value of 16.5 V.

Comment: So the whole story (a voltage source that does not cause sinking current source in Spice) comes from here Andy :D

Comment: Look at the voltage on the TVS; if it remains at 15.3 volts whilst the input is at 16.5 volts then you have used the wrong protection diodes on the input. This is why I suggested you look at the diode data sheet.

Comment: @Electronx if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: hi Andy, I will vote for the answer after a few tries, I have it in mind.

Comment: @Electronx I'm not sure what you mean by "a few tries"? Are you still unable to understand my answer and, if so, what help do you need?

Comment: The pcb that ı designed  is in production, after oscilloscope test and results ı will share the results and  ı will accept your answer